# TypeError: Cannot set property 'prop' of undefined

Tags: javascript

Скажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема?
Нужно написать функцию, которая будет дополнять/изменять коллекцию.

```js
// Setup
var collection = {
    "2548": {
      "album": "Slippery When Wet",
      "artist": "Bon Jovi",
      "tracks": [ 
        "Let It Rock", 
        "You Give Love a Bad Name" 
      ]
    },
    "2468": {
      "album": "1999",
      "artist": "Prince",
      "tracks": [ 
        "1999", 
        "Little Red Corvette" 
      ]
    },
    "1245": {
      "artist": "Robert Palmer",
      "tracks": [ ]
    },
    "5439": {
      "album": "ABBA Gold"
    }
};
// Keep a copy of the collection for tests
var collectionCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(collection));

// Only change code below this line
function updateRecords(id, prop, value) {
  if(value!==""){
    if(prop=="tracks"){
      if(!collection.id.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
        collection.id.prop = [];
      }
      collection.id.prop.push(value);
    }
    else{
      collection.id.prop = value;
    }
  }
  else{
    delete collection.id.prop;
  }
  
  return collection;
}

// Alter values below to test your code
updateRecords(5439, "artist", "ABBA");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так делать копию объекта я бы не додумался :)
Проще, например, так:

```
let copy = Object.assign(collection);
```

Вы используете доступ через точку, что равносильно вызову свойства по этому имени.
Если имя строка/переменная/ключ_с_невалидными_символами, то используйте скобочную нотацию:

```
let prop = 'data';
alert(someObject[prop]); // Будет равносильно someObject.data
```

Если бы `prop` было бы равно `tracks`, ошибка вылетела бы ещё на `collection.id.hasOwnProperty(prop)` по той же причине, но с другой ошибкой.

---

Лучше так:

```js
// Setup
let collection = {
    "2548": {
      "album": "Slippery When Wet",
      "artist": "Bon Jovi",
      "tracks": [ 
        "Let It Rock", 
        "You Give Love a Bad Name" 
      ]
    },
    "2468": {
      "album": "1999",
      "artist": "Prince",
      "tracks": [ 
        "1999", 
        "Little Red Corvette" 
      ]
    },
    "1245": {
      "artist": "Robert Palmer",
      "tracks": [ ]
    },
    "5439": {
      "album": "ABBA Gold"
    }
};
// Keep a copy of the collection for tests
// - var collectionCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(collection));
let collectionCopy = Object.assign(collection);

// Only change code below this line
function updateRecords(id, prop, value){
  if(value !== ""){
    if(prop === "tracks"){
      if(!collection[id].hasOwnProperty(prop)){
        collection[id][prop] = [];
      }
      collection[id][prop].push(value);
    }else{
      collection[id][prop] = value;
    }
  }else{
    delete collection[id][prop];
  }
  
  return collection;
}

// Alter values below to test your code
console.info(updateRecords(5439, "artist", "ABBA"));
// Знаю что это битлы, но зато добавление в tracks проверено и работает
console.info(updateRecords(5439, "tracks", "All you need is love"));
```